# How to undelete my question that i deleted?

Tags: feature-request

An [answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/25230/11563) i gave many months ago got no votes and was rejected (via a comment) by the OP.
I deleted it yesterday -- after briefly buying the OP's argument.
Today, i had a rethink and again believe it to be a valid answer.
How can i undo my own deletion?
If i try to **Undelete** it, i get a pop-up saying i need 6 votes to undelete it, which i suppose is reasonable when the community or a moderator deletes a post, but not when it was my own (hasty) deletion of my own post.

Comment: Hi, feature-request tag is meant for a different purpose: *"You have an idea for a new feature, or for a change to the existing functionality."* I have edited your question with a more appropriate tag. Thanks!

Comment: I *did* want a change to existing functionality: I wanted the system to recognize that *I* was the one who deleted my own question and it should let me undelete it. (That may not be a wise change but that *is* was i was asking.)

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can ask for help, moderators can do it for you.

I guess it is in the rules as it is to stop people from hiding an unwelcome answer and then undeleting when people had forgotten it.

So if you give a link to the post we, mods, can help you.
Found it, (I overlooked your link at first,) and undeleted for you.

Comment: Thanks. And i'd ask for help via meta, or via Flag?

Comment: Either way will work but a flag is often easier.